# How to dismiss custom dialog

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm using the [cool_alert](https://pub.dev/packages/cool_alert/example) library to show custom alerts to my app. But i can't find any way to dismiss a custom alert.

I'm showing the alert with this code below:

```
CoolAlert.show(
    context: context,
    type: CoolAlertType.success,
    title: 'Profile updated',
    text: "Your profile informations has been updated successfully!",
    loopAnimation: false,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `showCancelBtn:true`. Default it is false. Also, you can use `onCancelBtnTap`

```dart
await CoolAlert.show(
  .....
  cancelBtnText: "Cancel",
  showCancelBtn: true,
  onCancelBtnTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
     }
);
```